# Call hidden div with onclick

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have a div for a button which I want to click and replace the contents on the page with a hidden div. Keep in mind this works without the onclick function (flashes the first div, then goes straight to 2nd) but when I add onclick it doesn't work.

```
<div id="next" class="button" name="somename"></div> 

<script>
     $("next").click(function () { 
           $('#div1').fadeOut('medium',function(){$('#div2').fadeIn('medium');}
     });
</script>
```

The button class has some css properties and an image to be used as a button.

Comment: well you are missing the "#" just before "next"..

Comment: i know you are looking for jquery toggle function: `.toggle` try this: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: why he forget when he put that for div1!!!

Comment: It appears the Poster wants to use a fade effect in which case [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) would be more apt.

Comment: I'm not looking to hide or show the first div, I want to hide it permanently and display the 2nd div only

Comment: yes I realize that, it's just a typo but doesn't work either way, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is just adding a onclick handler to the div in question. You're not actually triggering that click. For that, you'd need a simple `$('#next').click();`, or `$('#next').trigger('click');`

Comment: He doesn't want to trigger the click, just setup the click event.

Comment: The onclick handler is being assigned after the div has been created, so you are correct to say that just assigning a handler to the div's onclick event does not actually trigger that event. However it looks like it would still work if the user were to actually click on the div... Well, it would work if it were `$("#next")` but that's already been said by other posters. I guess it depends on when the OP is expecting the behavior to happen (right as the assignment happens [incorrect] or when the user clicks the div [correct])

Comment: I want them to be able to click that div and call the fade effect to hide the first div with the 2nd. Do I need .trigger somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If "next" is an ID then you need $("#next").click
You also need a second div (assumed you have it)
The onclick should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing the div correctly in jQuery- you forgot the # to reference the id.

```
 $("next").click(function () { ... }
```

should be

```
 $("#next").click(function () { ... }
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference